# input image dissappearing when clicked in Chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, mouseevent, forms

Here is the code for an image input to submit a form. It looks nice in latest firefox and IE. In Chrome (version 30.0.1599.101 m) the image disappears when clicked, showing an empty outline with alt text inside until the form submits. It doesn't matter much but is annoying and I'd like to fix if possible. Anybody know how to prevent this?

The onmousedown/onmouseout works in Chrome but there is a delay in image change suggesting the display:none image is not caching. This doesn't happen in IE or Firefox.

Note: The external CSS is not relevant as its only margin, border, etc.

```
<input class="buy_butt" src="/img/gen/buy-now.gif" id="addtocart" name="addtocart" onmousedown="this.src='/img/gen/buy-now-onclick.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/img/gen/buy-now.gif'" alt="add to cart" type="image">
<img src="/img/gen/buy-now-onclick.gif" style="display:none;" alt="add to cart onclick">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work for me in Chrome. However, did you try preloading the image manually as part of the onload event of your page?

Inside your head tag include:

```
<script language = "JavaScript">

function preloader() {
    buyNowOnClick = new Image(); 
    buyNowOnClick.src = "/img/gen/buy-now-onclick.gif";
}

</script>
```

Call preloader in the onload event of the document. That is:

```
<body onload="javascript:preloader()">

<!-- Your Page goes here -->

</body>
```

With this, there is no need to add the hidden img tag and your image will already be preloaded so you should not expect any delay switching images the way you do.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well in Chrome, and it didn't appear to be a preload issue, since the normal and hover image appeared just fine, until the input was clicked, at which point the input was replaced by a box with the alt text.  Via http://mir.aculo.us/2011/12/07/the-case-of-the-disappearing-element/, adding this style to the input made the issue go away:

-webkit-transform: translateZ(0.00001px);